# PyGears converting Integer to Fixed Point

Tags: python, pygears

I would like to convert my interface which is Uint[10] to Fixed Point 10.16, 16 bits in total, 10 for whole part and 6 bits for fraction. How to do it?
Code for interface is below:

```
from pygears.typing import Uint

a = Intf(Uint[10])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert Uint[10] to Fixp[10, 16]. Because element of Uint[10] is between 0 and 1023 wich is far grater than max elemet of Fixp[10, 16].

You can convert Uint[10] to Fixp[11, 16] like this:

```python
result = []
@gear
def consumer():

    data = once(val=[255], tout=Uint[10])
    res = data | Fixp[11, 16]
    collect(res, result=result)


consumer()
sim()
```

Result: [Fixp11, 16]